# How to find SSH user logged in and their display number

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openbox

Running Ubuntu 12.04. I have many users logged in via SSH and opening an [Openbox](http://openbox.org/wiki/Main_Page) session. How do I loop through all the logged in users and their display number so that I can execute a command for specific users?

The command would be the extension of restarting a Java application that they have open.

I have  tried `who -a`, but it doesn't seem to list any SSH users and their display number.  I am able to get display numbers via cd `/tmp/.X11-unix` but not their corresponding user login.

Answer (score 2):

Try `who` or `who -a`. it displays the user name, TTY/PTS (with id), and the display number (if local) or remote location. See here for the [manpages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/who.1.html).

This is one local session and two SSH sessions:

```
:~$ who
myuser tty7         2015-09-10 00:44 (:0)
myuser pts/2        2015-09-13 19:32 (MyWorkstation.net)
myuser pts/4        2015-09-13 19:34 (MyWorkstation.net)
```

Comment: I have tried who -a, but it doesn't seem to list any SSH users and their display number. I am able to get display numbers via cd /tmp/.X11-unix but not their corresponding user login.

Comment: you should be able to determine the session by start time, as it will be the create date for the file in `/tmp/.X11-unix`. Also, if your connections are creating displays via X11, then you can find the display from `ps aux | grep X` and note the display number in the command, like `/usr/bin/Xorg :0`

Comment: `who` still provides display numbers on Xubuntu 19.10.